# How can I convert from U+0043 to C using Python?

Tags: python, unicode

Does something exist that can take as input U+0043 and produce as output the letter C, maybe even a small description of the character ( like `LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C` )?

EDIT: the `U+0043` is just an example. I would like a generic solution please, that could work for as many codepoints as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[unicodedata.name](http://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.name) looks promising. You need a bit of (trivial) parsing, of course, if you have a string input like `U+0043`.

Answer (score 3):

The hackish way:

```
import unicodedata

codepoint = b"U+0043"
char =  codepoint.replace('U+', "\u").decode('unicode-escape')
# or char = unichr(int(codepoint.replace('U+', ''), 16))

print char
print unicodedata.name(char)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import unicodedata
print unicodedata.name(u'C') # or unicodedata.name(u'\u0043')
# LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
```

Comment: Ok, but how do I get from `U+0043` to C?

Answer (score 0):

You could do `chr(0x43)` do get `C`.

Comment: I would like this to work with any codepoint, not restrict only to ascii.